# What is a good way to stop all pthreads without using mutex or global variables?

Tags: c, pthreads

Say hypothetically you do not know about mutex_locks and you are not allowed to use global variables in your program, what can you do in order to stop all running pthreads if one returns a successful variable?

For example you have a data structure that you pass to the pthread that contains :

```
typedef struct {

    char * string1;         //info from argv[1]
    char * string2;         //info from argv[2]

    int id;                 //thread id

} dataStruct;
```

and while creating the pthreads in main.c you create them as such :

```
dataStruct dataStr[nbThread];           //array of dataStructs for each thread
pthread_t tabThread[nbThread];          //Pointers for thread 1

for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; ++i) {    //initiation of threads...
    dataStr[i].string1 = argv[1];

    pthread_create(&tabThread[i], NULL, thread, (void *)&dataStr[i]);   //create pthreads and
}   

for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; ++i) {
    pthread_join(tabThread[i], (void**)&(ptr[i]));                      //join threads
    //printf("\n return value from thread[%d] is [%d]\n",i, *ptr[i]);
}
```

Now one of those threads finds what you were hoping to achieve, how can you get all the threads to stop simultaneously?

Can I have a pointer in the struct that points to a variable in the main that can be changed to true as soon as a thread is successful?

Can I use the return value by the pthreads to somehow stop them all?

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the pointers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Stop" as in *pause*? Or "stop" as in *kill*?

Comment: `raise(SIGABRT);`, or equivalently `kill(getpid(), SIGABRT);`, or equivalently `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), SIGABRT);` will stop all threads in the finest manner you can define "simultaneously".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude stop as in kill all the threads. pthread_cancel / exit

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis what is SIGABRT? Also since all the pthreads are running simultaneously, wouldnt pthread_kill just kill the current running thread?

Comment: Then cancel them, definitely cancel them. Killing the threads outright will do just that, and not let you clean up properly after yourself. If you cancel the thread they at least have a chance to clean up first before exiting.

Comment: SIGABRT is a signal (`man signal`). The answer to the second question is no.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is that pthread_cancel(NULL) does correctly end the current thread, but the others running along side continue running.

Comment: You do have an array of all threads, loop over it and call `pthread_cancel` passing the `pthread_t` for each thread. Much like you do when joining the threads.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis so it works, is there a way to hide the "Aborted (core dumped)" value returned at the end?

Comment: Just use `exit` to quit your program. This ends all threads and even does some cleanup.

Comment: @JensGustedt exit(0); quits the successful thread but not the ones running along side.

Comment: `exit` terminates the process, and by definition all threads of the process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I put into the struct the pointers to each thread. In the thread when one is successful I loop over all the threads to cancel them. It compiles without any issues but gives me a segfault.

Comment: Well that is a subject for another question. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can use for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed the question a bit. Please take a look at the edits.

Comment: You need to rethink both your design and your question. If you `pthread_join` all threads from the main thread, you are going to have to find another way to signal work completion among threads. Typically this is done by other condition variables, and therefore mutexes, or a synchronising data structure (typically a queue), and therefore mutexes. While we can answer the question, it is useless unless you have a supporting application design. Or an MVCE.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Basically I'm writing a brute force cracker where I choose how many threads to execute. Thread one tries all passwords starting with (a -> d), thread 2 (e -> h) etc etc. Say the password is axxxx, thread 1 finds it but 2 keeps searching. I'd just like to stop thread 2 at the same time as thread 1.

Comment: Please put all that information in the question, with an MVCE.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Found a solution myself in the end. Please check the answer I wrote.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So I found the answer myself in the end. It was much simpler than I assumed.

So in my main I created a "flag" variable as such :

```
int flag = 0;
```

Then in my struct I added the following pointer :

```
int * ptrTrouve;        //ptr on address of flag in main.c
```

Then while creating all the pthreads and before passing the pthread_create the structs in the parameter, I made ptrTrouve point to the address of the flag. I did it as such

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; ++i) {            //initiation of threads...

    dataStr[i].id    = i;                       //thread ID in appropriate struct

    dataStr[i].ptrTrouve = &flag;               //where the value of flag is stored

    pthread_create(&tabThread[i], NULL, thread, (void *)&dataStr[i]);   //create pthreads and
}
```

Finally in my thread, while the functions run simultaneously, they permanently verify if :

```
*(dataStr.ptrTrouve) == 0
```

If one of the threads is successful, they change the value of the flag like this :

```
*(dataStr.ptrTrouve) = 1;
```

As each thread is constantly monitoring the value of the flag (*(dataStr.ptrTrouve)) they can all run at the same time. As soon as the flag changes, this is what happens:

```
if(*(dataStr.ptrTrouve) == 1){              //if successful 
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I hope this solution can help others in the future.

Comment: Your "solution" is a data race. It's been noted before.

Comment: Seeing as I'm not coding a nuclear missile system, I don't think its the end of the world I theres a data race issue. Its probably not the best solution but it IS a solution. @MichaelFoukarakis

Comment: Instead of writing code which might _sometimes appear to work_, check out my answer, and solve your issue definitively and reliably.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to accomplish what you wish with POSIX threads:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10

pthread_mutex_t cv_mutex;
pthread_cond_t notification_cv;
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

bool allfinished = false;

void *worker(void *arg) {
    /* Allow cancellation, */
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    /* and get canceled at any time, not just at cancellation points: */
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    int loop = 0;

    while (true) {
        printf("iteration %d\n", loop);
        ++loop;

        /* Do some "work": */
        ;

        /* We specifically assume the only shared state
         * is the condition variable, and that the workers
         * share NO OTHER STATE.
         * If they do, adjust the critical section accordingly,
         * perhaps with a 2nd mutex.
         */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cv_mutex);
        if (loop > 5) { /* Simulate "work end" */
            allfinished = true;
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&notification_cv);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&cv_mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cv_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *master(void *t) {
    /* Lock mutex and wait for signal. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cv_mutex);

    /* Loop because a thread might be awoken from its
     * waiting state even though no thread signalled
     * the condition variable:
     */
    while (!allfinished)
        pthread_cond_wait(&notification_cv, &cv_mutex);
    printf("master: woken up.\n");

    /* Unlocking the mutex allows workers to signal the condition variable again,
     * but this is irrelevant as we're heading for end-of-life:
     */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cv_mutex);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS - 1; ++i) {
        pthread_cancel(threads[i]);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    /* Initialize mutex and condition variable objects */
    pthread_mutex_init(&cv_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&notification_cv, NULL);

    /* For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state: */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    /* Keep a separate `master` thread, which may be doing other bookkeeping: */
    pthread_t s;
    pthread_create(&s, &attr, master, NULL);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof threads / sizeof *threads; ++i) {
        if (!pthread_create (&threads[i], &attr, worker, NULL) ) {
            printf("worker %zu created\n", i);
        }
    }

    /* Wait for all threads to complete. This will not wait forever because the master
     * thread will cancel all of the workers:
     */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof threads / sizeof *threads; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        printf("worker %zu done\n", i);
    }
    pthread_join(s, NULL);
    printf("master done\n");

    /* Clean up and exit */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&cv_mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&notification_cv);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I really do appreciate the time you took to answer my question @michael but my question specifically said **not to use mutex or semaphores or global vars**. We have just started studying POSIX threads in my course so for the first graded program we weren't supposed to use mutex/semaphores. For that program, the method I found worked out best. We started thread synchronization this week so I'll be taking a look at your answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment yet, so I'll reply :

I think you could simply use a boolean value defined in your main and pass it to your threads as reference/pointer.

Then when one of your thread ends it has to change this variable value to notify all the others. Thus they must check the state of this variable within their process loop in order to break from it.

There should be no problem of concurrency/data race (as highligthed by @EOF) with these operations on the boolean if you use C11 and the [_Atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) keyword.

In the end your loop calling `pthread_join` will make your program wait until every threads returned cleanly.

Comment: What you are proposing is called a *data race*. It is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: My bad, indeed it's not fully safe, so maybe using C11 and [_Atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) keyword on the boolean variable ?

Comment: @Wexiwa I don't know why your solution got downvoted but this is exactly what I did in the end. Works perfectly. Though instead of a boolean, I used an int.